# Tensorflow-gpu with conda: where is CUDA_HOME specified?

Tags: tensorflow, conda, miniconda

Back in the days, installing `tensorflow-gpu` required to install separately CUDA and cuDNN and add the path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `CUDA_HOME` to the environment.

Now, a simple `conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.9` takes care of everything. Removing the `CUDA_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the environment has no effect whatsoever on tensorflow-gpu.

**Question**: where is the path to CUDA specified for TensorFlow when installing it with anaconda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install tensorflow-gpu, it installs two other conda packages:

```
cudatoolkit:       9.0-h13b8566_0          
cudnn:             7.1.2-cuda9.0_0
```

And if you look carefully at the tensorflow dynamic shared object, it uses RPATH to pick up these libraries on Linux:

```
(tflow) $ ldd $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so | grep -E 'cufft|curand'
    libcufft.so.9.0 => /tmp/wani.1533146686/tflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../../../../libcufft.so.9.0 (0x00007fbb9454a000)
    libcurand.so.9.0 => /tmp/wani.1533146686/tflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../../../../libcurand.so.9.0 (0x00007fbb905e4000)

(tflow) $ ldd $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so | grep cudnn
    libcudnn.so.7 => /tmp/wani.1533146686/tflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../../../../libcudnn.so.7 (0x00007fd73b55d000)
```

The only thing is required from you is `libcuda.so.1` which is usually available in standard list of search directories for libraries, once you install the cuda drivers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following command took care of it automatically:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```